# Bedeutungen von "ankommen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler. Als ich die Bedeutungen von "ankommen" genauer betrachtet habe, habe ich bemerkt, dass ich manchen davon in Korpora der letzten Jahre gar nicht begegne, die in Wörterbüchern allerdings vorhanden sind: "Eine Stellung finden" (Er ist in diesem Betrieb als Buchhalter angekommen), "gegen jmdn./etw. ankommen" (Er kommt nicht gegen sie an) und "in bestimmter Weise auf jmdn. wirken" (Dies hat ihn sauer angekommen). Was ist eure Meinung darüber? Wird "ankommen" in der Gegenwart in diesen Bedeutungen verwendet?

Comment: 1 und 2 ja, 3 habe ich noch nie gehört. Habe aber keine Belege, daher nur Kommentar und keine Antwort.

Comment: *»Was ist eure Meinung darüber?«* ist eine ganz, ganz schlechte Frage hier auf Stackexchange und normalerweise ein Grund dafür, die Frage zu schließen. Einer der 5 möglichen Schließungsgründe ist *»Opinion-based«* mit der Erklärung *»This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.«* Stackexchange ist kein Diskussionsforum, bei dem es um den Meinungsaustausch der Mitglieder geht, sondern eine faktenbasierte Frage-Antwort-Plattform. Nachdem sich deine Frage aber durchaus mit Fakten beantworten lässt, ist sie trotzdem erlaubt.

Answer (score 1):

Wie [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ankommen) angibt, ist ein großer Anteil entweder *umgangssprachlich/salopp* oder *gehoben*. Dass sie sich somit für Tagespresse nur begrenzt eignen, erklärt, warum sie in den Korpora nur wenig erscheinen.

Da diese unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen in den Statistik-Werkzeugen nicht auseinanderzuhalten sind, bleiben sonst nur Mutmaßungen. Gehört habe ich die aufgeführten Bedeutungen alle.

Answer (score 0):

> Ludwig ist in diesem Betrieb als Buchhalter angekommen.

Solche Formulierungen hört man zwar selten, aber das ist ein durchaus korrekter Satz, der auch im Jahr 2023 verwendet werden kann. Er ist aber nicht als »Ludwig hat eine Stelle als Buchhalter bekommen« oder »Ludwig macht jetzt den Job eines Buchhalters« zu interpretieren. Der Satz bedeutet etwas anderes.

Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass Ludwig, nachdem er in seinem Leben schon viele andere Dinge gemacht hat, nun endlich seine Berufung gefunden hat, und sich als Buchhalter verwirklichen kann. Der Satz kann auch bedeuten, dass Ludwig zwar schon seit Monaten oder Jahren den Buchhalter-Job gemacht hat, sich bisher innerlich dabei aber nie als vollwertiger Buchhalter empfunden hat. Aber jetzt ist es so weit: Ludwig fühlt sich auch in seiner Selbstwahrnehmung als Buchhalter.

Bei *»in einem Beruf ankommen«* geht es also um das Ende einer Reise. Diese Reise ist aber keine physische Reise durch mehrere geographische Orte, sondern eine mentale bzw. emotionale Reise durch verschiedene Stadien des Lebens.

---

> Erwin wollte den Platz überqueren, aber er kam nicht gegen den heftigen Sturm an.
> Sandra hat sich um diese Stelle beworben, aber sie ist nicht gegen ihre MitbewerberInnen angekommen.

Sätze wie diese sind durchaus üblich. Dabei wird das Verb *ankommen* jedoch fast immer verneint (jemand kommt nicht gegen jemanden/etwas an). Diese Formulierung bedeutet, dass es zumindest im übertragenen Sinn einen Kampf gegeben hat, den das Subjekt des Satzes verloren hat. Erwin hat gegen den Sturm gekämpft und verloren, Sandra hat gegen ihre MitbewerberInnen gekämpft und verloren.

Um auszudrücken, dass jemand einen Kampf beginnt, gibt es auch das Verb *»angehen«: »Thomas ist vor der ganzen Belegschaft seinen Chef angegangen.«* Damit ist gemeint, dass Thomas seinen Chef attackiert hat. Das kann verbal, oder auch körperlich gewesen sein. Wenn der Chef dann aber die Auseinandersetzung für sich entschieden hat, wird man später über Thomas sagen, dass er damals nicht gegen seinen Chef ankam.

Mein Gefühl sagt mir aber, dass die Verwendung der Verben *angehen* und *ankommen* in dieser Bedeutung eher nur in Österreich und dem süddeutschen Raum gebräuchlich ist, und dass man die Verben in diesen Bedeutungen umso seltener verwendet, je weiter im Norden Deutschlands die Sprecher zuhause sind. - Aber das ist eine reine Vermutung! Andere Personen werden das in Kommentaren möglicherweise bestätigen oder widerlegen.

---

> Deine Entscheidung kommt mich übel an.

Das ist zwar korrektes Deutsch, wird in Wörterbüchern aber zurecht als *»gehoben«* markiert, und ich würde auch *»veraltend«,* wenn nicht sogar *»veraltet«* hinzufügen. Wer solche Sätze verwendet, will Bildung oder zumindest die Zugehörigkeit zu einer elitären Schicht signalisieren. Es mag sein, dass diese Konstruktion früher geläufiger war, aber sogar das zweifle ich an (ohne es belegen zu können).

Sätze wie diese findet man auch in Büchern, die als *»literarisch wertvoll«* bezeichnet werden, eben weil darin eine gehobene (und meist schon zum Zeitpunkt der Publikation veraltende) Sprache verwendet wird, die keineswegs der Alltagssprache der breiten Bevölkerung entspricht.

Comment: *ankommen* in der letzteren Bedeutung wird meinem Eindruck nach (auch wenn der Duden nicht "regional" sagt) im Norden Deutschlands (noch) wesentlich häufiger benutzt als woanders.

Comment: *gegen etwas/jmnd. ankommen* wird in Norddeutschland genauso verwendet.